# Prevent LibGDX game from completely stopping when paused

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my LibGDX game for android, if the user backs out of the game (either by pressing the home button or switching to another application) LibGDX's built in `pause()` method is supposed to run. Now, this is fine, and it works fine as well. My problem is that if I back out of the game to do whatever, and then rejoin the game, it has restarted the app completely (kind of like if every time you exited and rejoined in the middle of a game of Pacman your score would be zero and all the dots would be back).  For my screen switching, it is necessary that the game NOT restart every time the user exits, but simply enter the corresponding state to actually simulate the 'paused' game. How do I stop LibGDX/Android from killing the game altogether upon user exit, but simply pausing it?

Answer (score 6):

The libGDX application lifecycle matches the lifecycle of the Android Activity as documented in the [**ApplicationListener**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener.html) interface so you should expect the same behavior. When you press the home button while in a libGDX game then the pause method will be called, which is the same as onPause in Android. The game will go to the background but will stay in memory. However this is not guaranteed and the OS might release the games memory for other applications, there really is no way to get around this. In the case when the game comes back to the foreground and the game restarts you'll need to load the games state from when it was paused.

I've written my own [**article on how to save and load the game state using Json in libGDX**](http://www.steventrigg.com/libgdx-save-game-state-and-local-data-persistence/), maybe that will be useful to you.

Comment: If there's no easy way to do it, is this the way that many other applications do it? I wouldn't expect what I would consider a simple matter so unorthodox. I'm going to keep the question open for a little bit of time just to see if I get any other answers, but I'll read your article and take it into considerations. Thanks :P

Comment: To help keep the OS from releasing the resources you can also try to get the games memory profile as small as possible. In the pause method try to unload the games sound and graphics assets, a smaller memory profile will be less likely to be released by the OS. However it's still no guarantee but it might be a better user experience.

Comment: If I was going to search Google for other ways to handle this, what would I search for? A lot of my searches are coming up worthless, and I'd like to look at alternatives before I ultimately choose.

Comment: There is a bit of discussion on the libGDX forums if you do a search. I did find this which is relevant: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12310

Answer (score 1):

You should use Asset Manager to prevent it, here a good tutorial :
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager

the official doc :
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager

Load all of your textures with assets manager

Comment: This will solve the issue for app assets, but will not solve the issue for saving your game state - you need to save your game state yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, but I found the solution by:
Disable option in Developer options called
**- Don't keep activities** (Destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it)

Comment: This will only delay the situation where the Android OS releases your apps resources and memory, it will not fix it. The purpose of setting this developer option is so you can confirm that your app handles this situation successfully when it happens, as outlined in Steven Trigg's answer above.